# ADO container jobs using private container

Tags: azure-devops

I have an ADO pipeline I'm trying to run as a containerized job.  The yaml is setup with the following line:

```
container: myDockerHub/myRepo:myTag
```

Where that actually points to a tag in a private repo on DockerHub.  The job errors with a message that access to the repo is denied and may require a login.  Which is perfectly true.  It's a private repo that does require a login. But how do I tell ADO to login to the repo?

I have a service connection setup to DockerHub, and I use `docker login` successfully in other non-containerized jobs where a script is spinning up a docker image.  But since this is using the `container` global option, I don't see any way to "preface" it with a login instruction. What do I need to get it to work here?

I don't see anything about authentication on the [Microsoft documentation on container jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/container-phases?view=azure-devops)

Comment: check the `endpoint`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/container-phases?view=azure-devops#endpoints

Comment: Ah.  Thank you @ShaykiAbramczyk. I was misled by the documentation's statement that this was for "registries other than DockerHub".  I guess they really mean other than "public DockerHub registries".  Adding my Docker Hub service account to endpoints works.  i.e. `endpoint: 'My Docker Hub Connection'` where "My Docker Hub Connection" is what I called it in Project Settings-> Service Connections works perfectly.

Comment: And PR submitted to clarify the docs.  https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/pull/12178

Comment: Great! I've added it as answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your DockerHub service connection with the `endpoint` [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/container-phases?view=azure-devops#endpoints):

```
container:
  image: registry:myimage
  endpoint: private_dockerhub_connection
```

Comment: Per the PR in the comments to the question, the Microsoft documentation is now updated.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/container-phases?view=azure-devops#endpoints